# Installing Slycot in Python 2.7. Using a Windows 8

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-control

I am working with the [Python-Control Library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/control/0.7.0), there I need Slycot to implement LQR.

I am trying to install Slycot (I tried with the zip found at PyPI and from the Github repo), but I get the following error:

```
e\slycot\src\TG01ID.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\slycot\src\TG01JD.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\slycot\src\TG01WD.o build\temp.win-amd64-2
.7\Release\slycot\src\UD01BD.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\slycot\src\UD01CD.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\slycot\src\UD01DD.o build\temp.wi
n-amd64-2.7\Release\slycot\src\UD01MD.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\slycot\src\UD01MZ.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\slycot\src\UD01ND.o buil
d\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\slycot\src\UE01MD.o -LG:\Packaged_Software_bundles\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3\python-2.7.10.amd64\share\mingwpy\lib\gcc\x86
_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2 -LG:\Packaged_Software_bundles\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3\python-2.7.10.amd64\libs -LG:\Packaged_Software_bundles\WinPython-64bit-
2.7.10.3\python-2.7.10.amd64\PCbuild\amd64 -llapack -lpython27 -lgfortran -o build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\slycot\_wrapper.pyd" failed with exit status 1
```

I have been doing it using :

```
python setup.py install
```

Some help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Try the binaries from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#slycot, which require [numpy+mkl](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)

Comment: How do I install using the .whl file? @cgohlke

Comment: Got it thanks. :) Installed without any problem with pip.